# The way of logging at action of controller in Ruby on Rails for debug purpose

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just trying to know if router is reaching to specific action of controller.
In js, we are using `console.log` and `var_dump` in php.
I tried with `puts` but it didn't work and I think it's because of the reloading.
I need help from Ruby on Rails guru.
Regards!

Comment: Might be better off asking on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: It is logged by default at ":info" level. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Thank @AlexD.
What my fault was looking for log from the inspected console part of browser.
I tried to skim cmd and could find logs.
Thank you for your advice.